# How Open PHP File

Tags: php, save, configure

I like to try a simple PHP Project. I installed apache, mysql and phpmyadmin on my computer (linux- fedora). Everything worked fine so far - i can open and log in to phpmyadmin.

I created a simple "Hello World" php file to try. Sadly the browser wont open it. All I get is: "Not Found The requested URL /home/.../test.php was not found on this server." This is the URL into my browser "http://localhost/home/.../test.php"
Since I never worked with php before I figure it's a simple mistake. It seems I have saved the file at the wrong place. From what I have found out I need to save it at /var/www - but I cant find that directory on my computer.

Thank for the help in advance!

Comment: which operational system do you use?

Comment: I suppose it's just `http://localhost/test.php`

Comment: I use a Fedora 27. 
I installed Remi repository
I installed apache -> If I enter my IP into the browser the "Fedora Test Page" opens
I installed MySQL
I installed phpMyAdmin -> I can login through http://**myIP**/phpmyadmin

I couldn't install this: libapache2-mod-auth-mysql and php5-mysql

Might there be a problem with my installation? I have read the "var/www/" directory should be there if apache was installed correctly. But I can't find that directory

Answer (score 0):

Save your File in htdocs folder and then run it in browser. or you can also make other folder inside htdocs folder.
Example: localhost/htdocs/test.php.